# Use Apple Pay from an iOS SDK

Tags: ios, applepay

We provide an SDK for integration in partner apps.

Is it possible to use Apple Pay within the SDK to support purchases?

Will that require tight coupling with the host app, as Passkit is tied to app permissions?

Would it be preferable to use a web view for payment instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a wrapper to simplify apple setup process in host app. However, host app's developer still need to enable Apple Pay capability, setup merchant ID on his own

Apple Pay on the Web is recommended for website to support Apple Pay, not to use it as a Web View inside your app